# Why there is a log term in inverse document frequency in Machine Learning? We can also use without log, what is real use of log here?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I can also implement idf without log as well, what is the significance of using log  in idf?

Like -: idf = log(# of docs/# of docs in that word appear)

But why can't we use idf = (# of docs/# of docs in that word appear)

Comment: Please precise your programming language in the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the IDF is going to be multiplied with the term frequency TF. For very common words, the IDF is likely to be 1 if log isn't used, so even these common words will end up weighing more than the actual rare and useful words. With the `log`, the IDF can become 0 for the most common words, so their effective tf-idf becomes 0 too, and they can be ignored.